# Email validation in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am creating a user validation in MeteorJS using `accounts-base` and `accounts-password`

```
if( Meteor.users.find({"emails.address": checkEmail}) ) {
            Session.set('registerErrors', {email:'Email already exists'});
            return false;
} else {
            Session.set('registerSuccess', {email:'Valid Email'});
}
```

I have this in part of my validation. The only problem is that it returns all email address as 'Email already exists'

Comment: `find` returns a cursor, which always is truthy. You probably meant to use `findeOne`.

Comment: @PeppeL-G I've tried findOne as well... It won't work for some reason... : (

Comment: Remember that the emails fields is an array ([see here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users)). However, the comments says "*each email address can only belong to one user*", so I don't think you need to validate this.

Comment: @PeppeL-G The only reason I want to verify it is to show the error message in the register page I've created. Is there no way to do this?

Comment: Use `Accounts.createUser` to create a new user. The callback you pass to it will get called with an error message if the given email address already is registered. Of course you can do your own check, but you don't have access to all users' email addresses on the client, so you still need to ask the server.

Comment: @PeppeL-G I guess thats the only way to do it.. I was doing it that way for now.. Thank you! I was only frustrated because ```if( Meteor.users.findOne({username:checkUsername}) ) ``` was working fine!